# How to come back to the first row in an array when you reach the end?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know how to change the background color of a UITableViewCell. But I have an array for maybe 5-8 different colors and I want the cells in a table to go through the array and use each background color in the order, and repeat the order if the number of cells is greater than colors. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering you have a `colorArray`, for example:

```
NSArray *colorArray = @[[UIColor whiteColor], [UIColor blueColor], [UIColor blackColor], [UIColor purpleColor], [UIColor grayColor], [UIColor greenColor]];
```

You simply set the `cell.backgroundColor`to `colorArray[indexPath.row%(colorArray.count)]` in the `UITableViewDelegate`'s `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Answer (score 0):

So maybe you should change the title of your post, because your question is : how to come back to the first row in an array when you reach the end. You can use modulo, which gives you the rest of a division : `indexPath.row % yourArray.count` : if it is 8, the result is :

```
...
7 % 8 = 7
8 % 8 = 0
9 % 8 = 1
etc.
```

You divide by 8, if you cannot, you take the rest of the division (`7 % 8` : you cannot divide by 8, so you take 7 ). `8 % 8` : you can divide by 8, but there is nothing left, so the result is 0.